# Convert rules written in PMD to sonar custom rules

Tags: java, sonarqube, pmd, sonar-plugin

I'm using PMD to add custom rules to my repository. Right now I'm planning to use sonarqube to analyze my local repositories. Is there any way to convert custom rules written in PMD to sonar custom rules.

Answer (score 1):

There is no conversion utility for this. You'll have to re-implement each rule using the SonarJava APIs. Fortunately, there is a tutorial for writing custom SonarJava rules: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101

Comment: Ya. I went through the tutorial. But the tutorial teaches how to write new coding rules. But my need is to convert rules written in PMD to sonar rules

Comment: See my expansion @ManojKumar